# How to stack blocks with exact heights/positioning in WPF flowdocuments

Tags: wpf

I need to use WPF flowdocument to create a letter front-page that matches at least part of DIN 5008 standard which tells us where each particular block of text (return address, recipient name etc) needs to go.    Specifcially I need to stack blocks on top of each-other and specify the exact height in millimetres of each block.

So how do I get my exact heights even though most FlowDocument elements don't have a `Height` property?   Or if I can't have exact heights, what workaround can I use?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/DIN_5008%2C_Form_A.svg
[image: Low-res preview of DIN 5008 standard page A.]

Comment: Sounds like fixed document would be the better choice. From [Documents in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx): "Fixed documents are intended for applications that require a precise "what you see is what you get" (WYSIWYG) presentation, independent of the display or printer hardware used. ... As part of its layout, a fixed document maintains the precise positional placement of content elements independent of the display or print device in use..."

Comment: Hmm, the time might come when I switch to FixedDocument's, but at the moment there is quite a lot of code invested in the FlowDocuments, including things things that need to, well, flow.  The diagram above is misleading in that I don't need to get all those details right, I just need to be able to make some boxes have specified sizes.  It shouldn't be hard.